# Misleading hover text in Favourite Button

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, design

Hover over the favourite button, and you see the following text (Spelling mistakes amended ;) )

"This is a favourite question (click again to undo)"

This implies that you have made the question a favourite already, and clicking will undo it.  But the text is the same regardless of if you have made it a favourite or not.

I came across a question that I set, and saw that it had a favourite count.  When I hovered and read the text, I clicked again to undo, not realising I had done that to my own question.  Of course this just increased the count as the first favourite was from someone else.

Can we amend the text to make it context insensitive?  Something like: "Click to toggle this question as a favourite" or "click to set/unset this question as a favourite"

Comment: Yup. Misleading. However, I *personally* don't see this as a big problem. However, someone who's new could have a problem.

Comment: Yeah, not a problem per se, but at work I'm involved in a "Continuous Improvement Program" or CIP, that addresses things like this.  It might just be spit and polish, but enough of these small improvements adds up, hence pointing it out.

Comment: I'd classify this as a `bug`. Might even get the attention of a team member. Shouldn't be too difficult to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Actually more tooltips are like this, thus it's by design and not a bug.
If you hover on the Upvote it displays:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

If you hover on the Downvote it displays:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not
>   useful

It does explain you what happens **when you click it**, thus not a bug.